# Insert Many to many relation in symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to insert a many to many relation in my symfony2 project.
I have followed all steps from [Symfony2-Doctrine: ManyToMany relation is not saved to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044864/symfony2-doctrine-manytomany-relation-is-not-saved-to-database)

ALL records are entered in items table except category_id...

Any idea ???

Comment: Please post your code from your entity, and also your code from the controller where you save persist the entity

Comment: It's because category_id shouldn't be in items table but in items_categories table (it's many to many relation so Doctrine will create third table to achieve this)

Comment: i have already category_id  in items_categories... Should i remove the column category_id from items table ??

Comment: you specify $categories field in your Item entity (Doctrine doesn't create any additional column like category_id)

Comment: i have $categories field in Item entity.... and it persists the data handsomely in category_items table with category and item id ,but i want know should i maintain category_id in items entity??

Comment: definitly no :) category_id is database concept. On ORM level you don't use columns - you just use entity properties

Comment: @Cyprian please post your comment as answer so that i can accept it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because category_id shouldn't be in items table but in items_categories table (it's many to many relation so Doctrine will create third table to achieve this)

You specify $categories field in your Item entity (Doctrine doesn't create any additional column like category_id). category_id is database concept. On ORM level you don't use columns - you just use entity properties

Answer (score 0):

> "i have already category_id in items_categories... Should i remove the column category_id from items table ??"

Actually your Item entity should not have category_id property (as the table), only "categories", smth like:

```
/**
  * @var array
  *
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="items")
  */
protected $categories = array();
```