# Selected attributes of genemu_jqueryselect2_entity not stored to database

Tags: symfony-forms, jquery-select2, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

I'm using genemu_jqueryselect2_entity for a multiple selection field within a form (located in an Sonata admin class) for a so called Uni (university) entity:

```
->add('courses', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity',array('multiple' => true, 'class' => 'PROJECT\UniBundle\Entity\Course'))
```

But the selected entries are not filled into my entity. With firebug I was able to detect, that the ids of the courses are passed correctly via POST.

Maybe the field is not correctly mapped to the Uni entity, but I have no idea why.

This is the adding method of my Uni entity, which doesn't even get called:

```
public function addCourse(\PROJECT\UniBundle\Entity\Course $courses)
    {
        $this->courses[] = $courses;

        return $this;
    }
```

How can I get the field to be mapped with the courses attribute of Uni? **How could I debug this?**

Any help will be appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the method addCourse isn't called.

Anyway, Tautrimas Pajarskas's answer was usefull to me so I gave an upvote.

The foreign key relationship was the necessary and missing part of my code.

I implemented it in the university sonata admin like this:

```
private function addUniToCourses ($university) {
    foreach($university->getCourses() as $course) {
        if(!$course->getUniversities()->contains($university)) {
            $course->addUniversity($university);
        }
    }
}

public function prePersist($university) {
        $this->addUniToCourses($university);
}

public function preUpdate($university) {
        $this->addUniToCourses($university);
}
```

This was the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing that method like this:

```
public function addCourse(\PROJECT\UniBundle\Entity\Course $course)
{
    $this->courses[] = $course;
    $course->setUniversity($this); // Or similar.

    return $this;
}
```

Otherwise foreign key is not set on a course row in the DB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the tip, but the addCourse method isn't even called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create method setCourses

```
public function setCourses(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $courses)
    {
         $this->courses = $courses;
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this method isn't called either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago: [Symfony2, $form->bind() not calling adder methods of entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102613/symfony2-form-bind-not-calling-adder-methods-of-entity)

**Solution**:
For the adder (addCourse()) to be called, you have to disable the `by_reference` option of the field:

```
->add('courses', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity',
      array(
          'by_reference' => false, // This line should do the trick
          'multiple' => true,
          'class' => 'PROJECT\UniBundle\Entity\Course'))
```