# Symfony Doctrine Many2Many relationship works only one way

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many

I'm developing a project management system with Symfony2. I have a project which can have one or more categories (many2many relation). After generating the two entities, forms and controllers with symfony, I can create a new category and assign some projects to it (categoryproject/1/edit) but I can't do the oposit, means I can't assign categories to a project in my project edit form (every time when i choose some categories and press update the choosen fields get white again). How is that possible? Here is my code:

The project entity: Dbe\DDBundle\Entity\Project:

```
manyToMany:
categoryProject:
  targetEntity: Dbe\DDBundle\Entity\CategoryProject
  mappedBy: project
```

The categoryProject doctrine:

```
  manyToMany:
project:
  targetEntity: Dbe\DDBundle\Entity\Project
  inversedBy: categoryProject
  joinTable:
    name: ProjectToCategoryProject
    joinColumns:
      category_project_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: false
    inverseJoinColumns:
      project_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: false
```

Here is the query i get from the Symfony Toolbar: why is there a questionmark?

```
    SELECT 
  t0.id AS id1, 
  t0.name AS name2, 
  t0.description AS description3 
FROM 
  CategoryProject t0 
  INNER JOIN ProjectToCategoryProject ON t0.id = ProjectToCategoryProject.category_project_id 
WHERE 
  ProjectToCategoryProject.project_id = ?
```

And here the add function:

```
    /**
 * Add categoryProject
 *
 * @param \Dbe\DDBundle\Entity\CategoryProject $categoryProject
 * @return Project
 */
public function addCategoryProject(\Dbe\DDBundle\Entity\CategoryProject $categoryProject)
{


    $categoryProject->addCategory($this);
    $this->categoryProjects[] = $categoryProject;

   // $this->categoryProject[] = $categoryProject;

    return $this;
}
```

Thanks in advance guys for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2-Doctrine: ManyToMany relation is not saved to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044864/symfony2-doctrine-manytomany-relation-is-not-saved-to-database)

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: sadly this wasn't the solution, I added the SQL query + the addCategoryProject method to the question above. do you find some errors?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, I made some error in reasoning :-)

```
    $entity = $em->getRepository('DbeddddBundle:Project')->findOneById($id);
    $comment = $em -> getRepository('DbeDddddBundle:Comment') -> findByProject($entity);
```