# Using doctrine OneToOne relation with condition in zf3

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, zend-framework3

I want to use Doctrine's relation OneToOne in entity User.
Eg. User has 2 exams - first and corrective. All exams are in one table but with flag **is_corrective**. How can I use OneToOne relation for this two types of exams for one user?

Comment: If you have more than 1 exams which belong to one user the relation can't be OneToOne it has to be OneToMany, if you need for some reason have OneToOne relation between user <-> exams, you should split exams into 2 tables: FirstExam and CorrectiveExam and remove the flag in both

Comment: Ok, so I must use getFirstExam() method to get first exam with condition and  getSecondExam() with corrective flag and add this entities to fields in User entity.
I thought I can cheat this way, but after minutes of thinking it could be bad solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**Single Table Inheritance**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)  for this.

1)Create entity **FirstExam**:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="exam_table_name")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="is_corrective", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"0" = "FirstExam", "1" = "CorrectiveExam"})
 */
class FirstExam
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

2)and entity **CorrectiveExam**:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CorrectiveExam extends FirstExam
{

}
```

3)then you can define 2 relations in the User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FirstExam")
 */
private $firstExam;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CorrectiveExam")
 */
private $correctiveExam;
```

The same table for both entities is used and "is_corrective" column is used as a discriminator.